# How do I lower a raster layer (map) by a shapefile (roads)?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a map layer and a road (shape file) layer. I want to put the roads “onto” the map layer by lowering the elevation of the map where the roads are.

I have tried to rasterize the shapefile but I just get a blacked out layer. My thought was to then use the raster calc to then add the two layers. But with a useless blacked out layer, I got nothing.

Comment: The raster layer is a digital surface model with ground heights?

Comment: @BERA Yes. A tiff heightmap

Comment: It would be easy to [Drape](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#drape-set-z-value-from-raster) the roads on the raster

Comment: @BERA OK, I was heading down this path, almost. I used the gdal/rasterize(overwrite) tool and it put the roads onto the raster. This was a step in the right direction! Now, how do I get the roads to be only 100 feet lower than their nearest neighbor? I put the integer of 1 for all of the roads, so it put them as 1 foot on the raster, next to elevations that vary but are into the 3k feet level.

Comment: @BERA So, maybe use drape to get the z values into the vector layer, then lower the whole thing by 100 feet, then use the overwrite tool? Maybe? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right path. I would rasterize the roads shapefile. It should be giving you values of 0 or 1 if it was rasterized correctly. Then you may have to reclass the raster because the roads should be 0 for the addition to the elevation layer. Then use the raster calculator to combine the two. What values are the "blacked out" raster giving you?